# Bash script not producing desired result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am running a cron-ed bash script to extract cache hits and bytes served per IP address. The script (ProxyUsage.bash) has two parts:

1. (uniqueIP.awk) find unique IPs and create a bash script do add up the hits and bytes
2. run the hits and bytes per IP

#### ProxyUsage.bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo gawk -f /home/maxg/scripts/uniqueIP.awk /var/log/squid3/access.log.1 > /home/maxg/scripts/pxyUsage.bash
source /home/maxg/scripts/pxyUsage.bash
```

#### uniqueIP.awk

```
{
  arrIPs[$3]++;
}

END {

  for (n in arrIPs) {
    m++;                               # count arrIPs elements
    #print "Array elements: " m;
    arrAddr[i++] = n;                  # fill arrAddr with IPs
    #print i " " n;
  }

  asort(arrAddr);                      # sort the array values

  for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {           # write one command line per IP address
    #printf("#!/usr/bin/env bash\n");
    printf("sudo gawk -f /home/maxg/scripts/proxyUsage.awk -v v_Var=%s /var/log/squid3/access.log.1 >> /home/maxg/scripts/pxyUsage.txt\n", arrAddr[i])
  }
}
```

#### pxyUsage.bash

```
sudo gawk -f /home/maxg/scripts/proxyUsage.awk -v v_Var=192.168.1.13 /var/log/squid3/access.log.1 >> /home/maxg/scripts/pxyUsage.txt
sudo gawk -f /home/maxg/scripts/proxyUsage.awk -v v_Var=192.168.1.14 /var/log/squid3/access.log.1 >> /home/maxg/scripts/pxyUsage.txt
sudo gawk -f /home/maxg/scripts/proxyUsage.awk -v v_Var=192.168.1.22 /var/log/squid3/access.log.1 >> /home/maxg/scripts/pxyUsage.txt
```

TheProxyUsage.bash script runs as scheduled and creates the pxyUsage.bash script.
However the pxyUsage.text file is not amended with the latest values when the script runs.
So far I run pxyUsage.bash every day myself, as I cannot figure out, why the result is not written to file.

Both bash scripts are set to execute. Actually the file permissions are below:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 maxg maxg  169 Mar 14 08:40 ProxySummary.bash
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg  910 Mar 15 17:15 proxyUsage.awk
-rwxrwxrwx  1 maxg maxg  399 Mar 17 06:10 pxyUsage.bash
-rw-rw-rw-  1 maxg maxg 2922 Mar 17 07:32 pxyUsage.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg  781 Mar 16 07:35 uniqueIP.awk
```

Any hints appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You can have a look at the [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) for steps to debug cron jobs that fail. In this case it's most likely because you haven't set up `sudo` to allow running your gawk script without your presence.

Comment: The cron job runs as intended. The first part (finding unique IPs) is successfully executed. The second part, parsing the squid access log is created and executed successfully; the result file (pxyUsage.txt) has the 06:10 timestamp (when the job is run daily, but it does not contain the new summary entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sudo(8) command requires a pseudo-tty and you do not have one allocated under cron(8); you *do* have one allocated when logged in the usual way.

Instead of mucking about with sudo(8), just run the script as the correct user.

If you cannot do that, then in the root crontab, do something like this:

su - username /path/to/mycommand arg1 arg2...

This will work because root can use su(1) without neding a password.

Comment: Thanks! I added the cron job via crontab -e, which I assume/believe to make the job run as mine. But, will try your root crontab suggestion.